# Using TryParse for Setting Object Property Values

Tags: c#, exception, refactoring, tryparse

I'm currently refactoring code to replace Convert.To's to TryParse.

I've come across the following bit of code which is creating and assigning a property to an object.

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     var p = new Person{ RecordID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ContactID"]) };

     list.Add(p);
}
```

What I've come up with as a replacement is:

```
var p = new Person { RecordID = Int32.TryParse(row["ContactID"].ToString(), out RecordID) ? RecordID : RecordID };
```

Any thoughts, opinions, alternatives to what I've done?

Comment: Not quite as readable - but if it works......

Comment: I agree with Dilbert. I think the one-liner is harder to read and would be painful to try to edit, or to step through in debugging. TryParse does sound like an improvement.

Comment: Since ContactID is a primary key in the database, converting to an Int32 will always succeed. The use of TryParse is misleading to the maintainer of the code, as it implies that the conversion can sometimes fail, which is not the case. I would stick with Convert.ToInt32.

Comment: I agree with Bradley Grainger, using TryParse here is wrong.

Comment: Why replace it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write an extension method.

```
public static Int32? ParseInt32(this string str) {
    Int32 k;
    if(Int32.TryParse(str, out k))
        return k;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to return 0 instead of null if false to be consistent with the original functionality?

Comment: In this case, because there should be a difference between failing to parse (null is returned) and paring 0 (0 is returned).

Comment: @Godless No. You would want something generic which is thus reusable. If you need to default to 0, then you would use ("1234".TryParseInt32() ?? 0).

Comment: This is also not readable. One would expect a method named "TryParseInt32" returns bool.

Comment: Renamed the extension method.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an alternative implementation `TryParse` which returns an `int?`:

```
public static int? TryParseInt32(string x)
{
    int value;
    return int.TryParse(x, out value) ? value : (int?) null;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var p = new Person { RecordID = Helpers.TryParseInt32(row["ContactID"].ToString()) ?? 0 };
```

(Or use a different default value, if you want - either way it'll be visible in your code.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest separate the TryParse part from initializer. It will be more readable.

```
int recordId;
Int32.TryParse(row["ContactID"].ToString(), out recordID)

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     var p = new Person{ RecordID = recordId };
     list.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: I thought of that as well (though you would need to put that part within the foreach block).

I was trying to go for terser code.  Especially if you are setting multiple properties while creating the object.

Comment: So why don't you create a constructor for Person that gets a DataRow and do what you want in it?

Comment: Why on earth should a Person class need to understand the semantics of relational-database persistence via ODBC and ADO.NET? Should it need to understand how to construct itself from a binary network stream? From CSV files? etc?

Comment: @Justice - Sure, you are right. I have totally nothing to say :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void TryToDecimal(string str, Action<decimal> action)
{
        if (decimal.TryParse(str, out decimal ret))
        {
            action(ret);
        }
        else
        {
            //do something you want
        }
}

TryToDecimal(strList[5], (x) => { st.LastTradePrice = x; });
TryToDecimal(strList[3], (x) => { st.LastClosedPrice = x; });
TryToDecimal(strList[6], (x) => { st.TopPrice = x; });
TryToDecimal(strList[7], (x) => { st.BottomPrice = x; });
TryToDecimal(strList[10], (x) => { st.PriceChange = x; });
```

Comment: He's question title is "Using TryParse for Setting Object Property Values".
What I response is use TryToDecimal for Setting Object Property such as LastTradePrice, LastClosedPrice, TopPrice, BottomPrice, PriceChange.